# I receive two messages using PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I do not understand why two messages come to my mail. 
The send function is launched once and the message about the successful sending displays once.

```php
<?php

require('class.phpmailer.php');

    $email = new PHPMailer();
    $email->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $email->From      = $_POST['mailmy'];
    $email->FromName  = '«Тэкс»';
    $email->Subject   = 'Ваша новая кухня почти готова.';
    $email->Body      = $_POST['mailText'];
    $email->AddAddress( $_POST['mailMeil']);

    $email->Send(); 
    echo 'Message has been sent';
    if (!$email->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $email->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}

?>
```

Comment: As well as the obvious mistake Ed pointed out, you're using an old version of PHPMailer. Update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call the `send()` method twice:

```php
$email->Send(); // first time
echo 'Message has been sent';
if (!$email->send()) { // second time
```

The code is doing exactly what you told it to do: send twice.

What you should do is store the result the first time and test that:

```php
$sent = $email->Send();
echo 'Message has been sent';
if (!$sent) {
```

As an aside: your `echo` statement there doesn’t make sense. You shouldn’t tell the user the message has been sent if you don’t know that yet.

Comment: Simply, you saved my day :) Thank you